# Loading specific icon size into TIcon from stream

Tags: delphi, icons, favicon, delphi-xe, glyph

My application downloads and displays favicons for specific websites. I followed Bing's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959160/load-jpg-gif-bitmap-and-convert-to-bitmap) for detecting image format from stream, but have hit another snag. Assuming an actual icon image, the code goes like this:

```
var
  icon : TIcon;
begin      
  icon := TIcon.Create;
  try
    icon.LoadFromStream( faviconStream );
    spFavicon.Glyph.Assign( icon );
  finally
    icon.Free;
  end;
end;
```

(**spFavicon** is TRzGlyphStatus from Raize Components. Its Glyph property is a TBitmap)

Now, this works, but sometimes the downloaded icon contains multiple images in different sizes, e.g. 32x32 in addition to the expected 16x16. For some reason the control's Glyph property picks the larger size.

How can I load **only the 16x16 size** into TIcon, or from TIcon into TBitmap?

Test favicon: http://www.kpfa.org/favicon.ico

*On edit:* If at all possible, I'd rather avoid saving the icon to a file first.

Comment: I know I can use icon.SetSize(16, 16) to shrink the icon, but the effect is not quite the same as if the original 16x16 image had been loaded.

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813845

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary source for the file format of an .ico file is on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997538.aspx). You should be able to work it out from this.

The `ReadIcon` procedure in Graphics.pas may be of use but I imagine that you only need to find 16x16 since you are looking for favicons.

If you wanted to get really cute, you could download the source to, say, Firefox, and see exactly how they handle favicons.

Comment: Strange that ReadIcon is not surfaced in the Interface section, or that there seems to be no "official" mechanism for this common need. For now I've found that invoking TIcon.SetSize(16, 16) before loading from stream seems to do the trick.

Comment: @moodforaday Yeah, that's the best way to do it. I wasn't aware of that particular nuance of ReadIcon - I've learnt something else today!