# Icon Resize Constructor Returning Incorrect Size

Tags: winforms, icons

I am trying to resize an ICO file embedded in my application by using [`System.Drawing.Icon(System.Drawing.Icon, int, int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142129(v=vs.110).aspx), but I am always getting an icon that is 32x32 pixels in size, the same size as the original icon (as returned by `Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(<main EXE file>)`. However, the ICO file in question also contains 128x128 and 256x256 pixel sizes. Why is it that I cannot get any larger size from the icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(...)` method uses internally this function from Shell32.dll:

```
IntPtr ExtractAssociatedIcon(IntPtr hInst, StringBuilder lpIconPath, out ushort lpiIcon)
```

(http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Icon.cs,8a5963a8e543d569), which returns the icon of one size only (for example 32*32). See: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.extractassociatedicon.

So, if you call this constructor overload:

```
Icon iconOfAnotherSize = new Icon(original, newWidth, newHeight)
```

then you will get the same icon as `original`, because there are no other sizes available.

To extract icons of another size you can try to use [PrivateExtractIcons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648075(v=vs.85).aspx) and here is [the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955288/extract-all-icons-from-an-exe-without-using-extracticonex) (Delphi).