# how to extract all icons from some exe files and insert them to other exe files using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, icons

I'm using Delphi.
I want to know how to extract (all) the icons from an exe file and insert them into another, preserving the order and the index of the icons.
I found some samples of Delphi code using Google but the problem is that it doesn't extract them all.
And I've found some compiled programs (exes) that do one or the other but not both.
Why do I need this: because I have to start some exe files (that have those icons) from virtualized applications. And I want to make some external exe files that have the same name and the same icons.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you need a resource editor.

Comment: Can't you just fix the code you've found so it extracts all the icons instead of just some of them? If you've found programs that do one part, and you've found programs that do the other part, what's keeping you from combining them into one that does both? Please be more specific about what part of the task you're having trouble with.

Comment: Sorry all for not replying sooner but I had no internet connection for many hours... @Rob, I tried but the Api functions/procedures that were used can't do that...

Comment: @Rob and I found programs as exe (I named them "compiled", sorry if it was wrong to do that) so how can I combine them into one...?

Comment: Extracting a single icon is easy (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813845/how-can-i-extract-a-image-of-specific-size-from-an-icon) but extracting them all probably requires that you at least borrow the code from a resource editor as shown in an answer below, to enumerate resources.

Answer (score 3):

The source is available for Colin Wilson's XN Resource Editor. It should have what you need.
http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm

Comment: Now I can acces the link. The program seems to work fine but it will take some work to extract the code that I need...

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you have the Delphi sample 'ResXplor'. If it's not distributed in your version it's also avalaible to download here: http://radstudiodemos.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/radstudiodemos/branches/RadStudio_XE/Delphi/VCL/resXplor/

Comment: In my version of Delphi (7) does not compile well:[Error] HexDump.pas(468): Operator not applicable to this operand type
[Error] HexDump.pas(483): Array type required
[Error] HexDump.pas(495): Operator not applicable to this operand type
[Fatal Error] RXMain.pas(12): Could not compile used unit 'HexDump.pas'
I will try in a newer version...

Comment: I compiled in a newer version of Delphi. The problem is that is doesn't see them well. For example, in one "branch", it sees all of them as 32x32x32. I tried to extract few of them and it is the same file to the last bit...

Answer (score 1):

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955288/extract-all-icons-from-an-exe-without-using-extracticonex) about extracting icons.  PrivateExtractIcons gives you access to specific image sizes in an icon resource, but you need to know the sizes ahead of time, and Microsoft warns that this method is [not for general use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648075).

There is a [working example](http://www.delphipraxis.net/566480-post7.html) of extracting the entire icon resource with all of the image sizes on Delphi Praxis.  The example has a problem with 256 pixel images, so it would have to be tweaked to account for these.

Comment: Very useful for a single icon, but it seems the OP wants to enumerate all the resources, so the PrivateExtractIcons will only get the one. Of course, since that's the main one, it seems like a great place to start!

Comment: Like I said, I'd avoid PrivateExtractIcons.  You can enumerate the RT_GROUP_ICON resources and use the Delphi Praxis example for each of them.